# How to scan text/string for certain words and gsub them out with desired words

Tags: ruby

I want to create a 'swearscan' that can scan user text and swap the swear words out for 'censored'. I thought I coded it properly, but obviously not because I'll show you what's happening. Someone please help!

And since its stackflow we'll substitute swear words for something else

```
puts "Input your sentence here: "
text = gets.downcase.strip

swear_words = {'cat' => 'censored', 'dog' => 'censored', 'cow' => 'censored'}

clean_text = swear_words.each do |word, clean|
text.gsub(word,clean)
end

puts clean_text
```

When I ran this program (with the actual swearwords) all it would return is the hash like so: catcensoreddogcensoredcowcensored. What is wrong with my code that it's returning the hash and not the clean_text with everything substituted out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
puts "Input your sentence here: "
text = gets.downcase.strip

swear_words = {'cat' => 'censored', 'dog' => 'censored', 'cow' => 'censored'}

swear_words.each do |word, clean|  # No need to copy here
  text.gsub!(word,clean)  # Changed from gsub
end

puts text  # Changed from clean_text
```

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong is that `gsub` does not change the original string, but you are expecting it to do so. Using `gsub!` will change the original string. You are also wrong to expect `each` to return something in it. Just refer to `text` in the end to get the replaced string.

By the way, if the replacement strings are all the same `'censored'`, then it does not make sense to use a hash there. You should just have an array of the swear words, and put the replacement string in the `gsub!` method directly (or define it as a constant in some other place).

Comment: It actually didn't work with the gsub! method. It still puts out the whole array (I changed it from hash to an array). Any thoughts?

Comment: sorry I don't know why or how but I missed the each part. Can you show me how you would do it with an array? I tried but it returned the error message "wrong argument type Array (expected Regexp) (TypeError)"